# Returning a Map from UDF(Java) in pig

Tags: java, dictionary, apache-pig

Let say I want to return a Map from a UDF (extends EvalFunc)

Map is String(Key), Object(value) . This Object is some Class having 4-5 fields of String.

I know that in order to return this complicated Map I need to override outputSchema.
But I am not able to figure out that what Schema I will be returning.

```
public class myUDF extends EvalFunc<Map>{
    public Map exec(Tuple input) throws IOException{
        Map<String, myClass> map = new HashMap<String, myClass>();
        // Create a Map
        return map;
    }

    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input){
        try{
            return new Schema... // How I will define my Schema
        }
        catch(FrontendException e){
            return null;
        }
    }


public myClass{
    String field1; String field2; String field3;
    // getters and Setters

}
```

Thanks and Regards,
Abhinav

Comment: public class myUDF extends EvalFunc<Map>{

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set a schema here. You are just returning a single element, a `map`, and Pig will know this based on the signature of the `exec` method.  Maps in Pig don't have any further schema, because the keys must be of type `chararray` and the values can be of any datatype.  So essentially they are always objects of type `Map<String, Object>`.

If you use this UDF, and then `DESCRIBE` your alias, you should see that Pig knows you have returned a map.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks, however can you point me in the right direction as to how to further process the map (pig chararray) in pig?  I'm not sure what to do next... i can't even dump it to see what it actually looks like.